# Angular RSS feed display

Tags: css, angular, rss

I want to call rss feed to a news bar that I made successfully the API call, but I stuck in how to display them beautifully. More specifically, I want the news feed auto-scroll from right to left one by one until the end of my feeds array then it starts again infinitely.

This is what I got: 
[image]

This is what I want (breaking news auto-scroll bar):

http://cdn.fearlessflyer.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/hades-home.gif

Here are my codes:

Template:

```
  <div class="container content-secondary">
  <div class="news-bar">
    <div class="ticker-wrap">
      <div class="ticker">
        <span *ngFor="let new of news" class="ticker__item">
            <a href="{{new.link}}" target="_blank">{{new.title}}</a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

***EDIT***: I found a workaround by using only CSS animation to display the news headlines as the way I wanted.

newsbar.component.css:

```
// News ticker animation
$duration: 180s;

@-webkit-keyframes ticker {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes ticker {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

.ticker-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 100%;  // offset items to begin
}

.ticker {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap; // display items in a line
  padding-right: 100%; // ensure items go before animations repeat (taken from parent due to inline-block)

  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-name: ticker;
         animation-name: ticker;
  -webkit-animation-duration: $duration;
          animation-duration: $duration;

  &__item {
    padding: 0 2rem;
  }

  a {
    color: $theme-color-secondary-contrast;
  }
}
```